# Specific array manipulation in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Considering 4 arrays:

```
$array1 = [
    0 => "Bill",
    1 => "John"
];

$array2 = [
    0 => "Gates",
    1 => "Wayne"
];

$array3 = [
    0 => "alive",
    1 => "dead"
];

$array1 = [
    0 => "man",
    1 => "man"
];
```

Question: How can I manipulate them to have this kind of results:

```
$array5 = [
    0 => [
        0 => Bill,
        1 => Gates,
        2 => alive,
        3 => men
    ],
    1 => [
        0 => John,
        1 => Wayne,
        2 => dead,
        3 => men
    ]
];
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 1) what have you tried. 2) specify which input arrays combine to produce which output arrays. 3) Is the order of names before their state important? Are ther always two entries in each array> And are we allowed to rely on that? Please update your question with current code.

Comment: Input: The 4 ones, Output, the last one. I've tried `array_map`. They all have the same number of entries

Comment: why not just use a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it. I haven't tested it though.

```
$inputs = array( $arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4 );
$output = array();

foreach( $inputs as $arr ){
  $output[] = array();
  foreach( $arr as $k=>$v ){
    $output[$k][] = $v;
  }
}
```

This should be pretty flexible. Handling any number of input array and creating # of output array = length of each input array.

Comment: Thanks @dan08, this one gives me the result I attempted (I have had to modify this: `$output[$k][] = $v;`

Answer (score 1):

You could just use array_map:

```
array_map(null, $array1, $array2, $array3, $array4)
```

This behaviour is mentioned in the PHP documentation for [array_map](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

> An interesting use of this function is to construct an array of arrays, which can be easily performed by using NULL as the name of the callback function

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = [
    0 => "Bill",
    1 => "John"
];

$array2 = [
    0 => "Gates",
    1 => "Wayne"
];

$array3 = [
    0 => "alive",
    1 => "dead"
];

$array4 = [
    0 => "man",
    1 => "man"
];



$array5 = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($array1); $i++) {
    $array5[$i] = array($array1[$i], $array2[$i], $array3[$i], $array4[$i]);
}

var_dump($array5);
```

Result:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'Bill' (length=4)
      1 => string 'Gates' (length=5)
      2 => string 'alive' (length=5)
      3 => string 'man' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'John' (length=4)
      1 => string 'Wayne' (length=5)
      2 => string 'dead' (length=4)
      3 => string 'man' (length=3)
```